# How to re-use result from a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to re-use the result from a SELECT statement to be used in `SQL EXISTS` statement.

The general idea looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col1=1
OR EXISTS (
  SELECT 1    // this is an exact copy of the SELECT statement above.
  FROM table 
  WHERE col=1
)
```

The actual SQL statement I am trying to reduce:

```
          "SELECT user_detail.user, user_detail.name, channel_member.role " +
          "FROM user_detail " +
          "JOIN channel_member ON user_detail.user=channel_member.user " +
          "AND channel_member.uuid=#{channelUuid} " +
          "WHERE user_detail.user=#{username} " +
          "OR EXISTS ( " +
          "   SELECT 1" +
          "   FROM user_detail " +
          "   JOIN channel_member ON user_detail.user=channel_member.user " +
          "   AND channel_member.uuid=#{channelUuid} " +
          "   WHERE user_detail.user=#{username} " +
          ")"
```

Comment: I suggest you post the sql, minus all the non-MySQL stuff.

Comment: **WARNING**: Use *prepared statements with placeholder values* and stay far, far away from string interpolation.

Comment: @tadman the 'select' annotation use prepared statement underneath, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your query will return the entire table if any row in the table matches the condition. What's the point of putting the condition in the main query?

Comment: If you want to reuse a subquery, use a CTE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: `col1=1` in outer query is excess

Comment: The way this is written it sure looks like things like `username` are *interpolated* which is a huge deal. That should be `user_detail.user=?`.

Comment: A window aggregation would probably be more performant than a subquery, although it can depend on how many rows we are dealing with

Comment: @Barmar the basic query does return all of the table. But the actual query does not (well it does but actually it only return the entire table from the result of previous query).

Comment: @Barmar thanks! WITH clause works like a charm.

Comment: @Akina would you kindly tell me the alternative? I would love to know the alternative.

Comment: If the actual query doesn't return the entire table, then there must be a difference between the main query and the subquery after `EXISTS`, which invalidates your basic premise.

Comment: @Charlieface would you kindly write an example with window aggregation?

Comment: @Barmar I posted the final solution that I am going to use, what do you think? Feel free to criticize it.

Comment: You should put it in an Answer, not the question.

Comment: @Barmar done. Please kindly check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 1 OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1    // this is an exact copy of the SELECT statement above.
              FROM table 
              WHERE col=1
             )
```

Doesn't really make sense.  It is saying to return all rows if `col = 1` is in the table -- but then it filters to check if *any* row has `col = 1`.  So it is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.col = 1);
```

I strongly suspect that you intend `NOT EXISTS` -- so get everything with `1`.  If there is no `1` then return everything:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 1 OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1    // this is an exact copy of the SELECT statement above.
                  FROM table 
                  WHERE col = 1
                 );
```

This should work fine with tables -- and is in fact probably optimal with the right indexes.

If "table" is really a complex query, then you might consider window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum( col = 1 ) as num_1s
      from t
     ) t
where col = 1 or num_1s = 0;
```

Comment: The `EXISTS` clause is intentional. I am trying to return **the entire table** if one of the row match with the WHERE clause.

Comment: I will look into window function tomorrow as recommended by Charlieface and you as well. I think SO's user need to aware of this window function, although I have not find the way to get the entire row with window function. +1

Comment: @kidfrom . . . Then why have `col = 1` in the `where` as well?  The first statement in my answer was wrong, so I fixed the answer.

Comment: My bad. I see your point. I eliminate the WHERE and EXISTS clause, theoretically, I hope it would reduce the query by square.

Answer (score 2):

**You can only do this if your version of MySQL supports window functions,** ie. version >= 8.0

You can use conditional window aggregation, like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN col1 = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER () AS CountMatches
    FROM table
) t
WHERE CountMatches > 0;
```

Depending on the number of rows matching to non-matching, this may be more or less performant. You need to test.

Comment: I am not sure how to use this. I tried to change the `Count` and `Case` clause, it only return 1 row. I will get back here tomorrow, thanks for the alternative. Anyway you can use this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7598b/2) to check so we can be on the same page.

Comment: Sorry,forgot the `OVER`

Comment: Yep, I will get back tomorrow. Too many foreign clause for me. I will learn more about `COUNT`, `CASE`, and `OVER`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any conditional statement on the query you are running you will need to wrap the query and put it in a FROM statement and then run the conditional outside of the query, like so....

```
SELECT aliasName.*

FROM
(SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col1=1) aliasName

WHERE EXISTS aliasName //this is the conditionl statement OUTSIDE of the query you built.
```

Let me know how you do...

Comment: I don't think this will work. `EXISTS` needs to be followed by a subquery.

Comment: I tried it on fiddle, it throws an error. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'aliasName' at line 8`

Answer (score 0):

For Mr./Ms. Barmar:

The idea

```
  // Idea:
  // If one of the row have col1 with value 1.
  // Then return all of the row, or return empty []
  // SELECT *
  // FROM table
  // WHERE col1=1
  // OR EXISTS (
  //   SELECT 1
  //   FROM table
  //   WHERE col=1
  // )
```

The solution

```
          "WITH temp AS (" +
          "   SELECT user_detail.user, user_detail.name, channel_member.role " +
          "   FROM user_detail " +
          "   JOIN channel_member ON user_detail.user=channel_member.user " +
          "   AND channel_member.uuid=#{channelUuid} " +
          ") " +
          "SELECT * " +
          "FROM temp " +
          "WHERE user=#{username} " +
          "   OR EXISTS ( " +
          "       SELECT 1" +
          "       FROM temp " +
          "       WHERE user=#{username} " +
          "   )"
```

The solution above use `WITH` clause as recommended by Mr./Ms. Barmar, I am posting this, so you can inspect whether this is logical or not.